# SSDT - Is there any way to log deployment history?

Tags: sql, sql-server-data-tools

I wonder if anyone know if there is any way to log deployment history to file?

We have a databaseproject and I can't find this option in SSDT and I can't find in the database when last deploy happend.

Comment: Good question. There's a refactor table but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Ok, I will check for that. Anyone who know if there is history record written in SQL server system databases when deploying?

Answer (score 0):

There's not an option for this directly, but you can do it through a post-deploy script. If you have any sort of automation running, you can also log your deploys through that. You might look at Jamie Thomson's example for this: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/10/19/maintaining-version-history-in-your-database-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx